# buckaroo return url flagged by mod_security

Tags: webserver, mod-security

Mod security flagged this buckaroo return url as a possible SQL injection attack

Short of excluding /you/pay/buckaroo from mod security rules all together from protections with `SecRule REQUEST_BASENAME "@beginsWith /you/pay" "id:1,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"`, how can I create a setting that will allow buckaroo urls and still block malicious attempts?

```
--74aba113-A--
[09/Aug/2019:10:02:00 +0100] XU02iPRLUgOFeK5fTjK1ewAAAAU 0.0.0.0 59104 0.0.0.0 443
--74aba113-B--
POST /you/pay/buckaroo?payment_push=fail HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 1189
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--74aba113-C--
brq_amount=2251.00&brq_currency=EUR&brq_customer_name=x+xxxx&brq_description=restbedrag+xxxx&brq_invoicenumber=000001%2f9&brq_issuing_country=NL&brq_mutationtype=Processing&brq_payment=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&brq_SERVICE_amex_CardExpirationDate=2099-09&brq_SERVICE_amex_CardNumberEnding=0000&brq_SERVICE_amex_Enrolled=U&brq_SERVICE_amex_MaskedCreditcardNumber=000000*****0000&brq_SERVICE_antifraud_Action=Warn&brq_SERVICE_antifraud_Check=Debit-+%26+Creditcard%3a+IP+rejected+payments+velocity+check&brq_SERVICE_antifraud_Details=The+count+(9)+reached+the+specified+threshold+(7)+over+period+365.00%3a00%3a00&brq_statuscode=690&brq_statuscode_detail=S005&brq_statusmessage=Error+processing+3-D+Secure%3a+SafeKey+not+available&brq_test=false&brq_timestamp=2019-08-09+10%3a48%3a58&brq_transaction_method=amex&brq_transaction_type=V036&brq_transactions=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEADXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&brq_websitekey=xxxxxxxxxx&CUST_transaction_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&brq_signature=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdf
--74aba113-F--
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 238
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

--74aba113-E--
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /you/pay/buckaroo
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>

--74aba113-H--
Message: Warning. detected SQLi using libinjection with fingerprint 'nf(1)' [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "68"] [id "942100"] [rev "1"] [msg "SQL Injection Attack Detected via libinjection"] [data "Matched Data: nf(1) found within ARGS:brq_SERVICE_antifraud_Details: The count (9) reached the specified threshold (7) over period 365.00:00:00"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.0.0"] [maturity "1"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-19"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"]
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator GE matched 5 at TX:anomaly_score. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "57"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"]
Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf"] [line "73"] [id "980130"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 5 - SQLI=5,XSS=0,RFI=0,LFI=0,RCE=0,PHPI=0,HTTP=0,SESS=0): SQL Injection Attack Detected via libinjection"] [tag "event-correlation"]
Action: Intercepted (phase 2)
Stopwatch: 1565341320248315 48158 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1565341320248315 48158; combined=29214, p1=702, p2=28301, p3=0, p4=0, p5=210, sr=104, sw=1, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/3.0.2.
Server: Apache
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"

--74aba113-Z--
```

Comment: And what is line 68 of `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf`? If you do not like this specific rule, why not disabling it?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i want to be protected elsewhere from attacks. Disabling is heavyhanded.

Comment: Yes, but first step would be to understand why this rule matches your query. And since we do not see the rule... Also the logs show `PCI/6.5.2` so maybe the rule is related to some PCI requirements which deal with processing of credit card data (is there a section 6.5.2 in their documentation maybe) and if it is so, it may mean your pattern of data exchange is not PCI compatible...

Comment: PCI requirement 6.5.2: https://kirkpatrickprice.com/video/pci-requirement-6-5-2-buffer-overflow/ "PCI Requirement 6.5.2 requires that your organization protects its applications from buffer overflows."

Comment: @PatrickMevzek it's the default configuration that comes with mod_security, i haven't changed a thing about it. But it's a good lead you provide,  as buckaroo is a mayor payment service provider.

Comment: "default configuration " which depends on the OS (we do not know which one it is), version (idem), modsecurity package version (idem), other customizations (idem). etc. I was just under the impression that if you added the rule in your question it would be easier for everyone to see why it matches and if it was legitimate or not. You can indeed as well ask the provider what it thinks about being flagged supposedly for some PCI non compliance.

Comment: Maybe it is this: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/v3.0/master/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf#L43

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'll update the question Monday with details,  but the OS is. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The log speaks about `nf(1)` being found in that specific argument value, but I do not see it myself (it is however it seems in the list of fingerprints used by the libinjection code used by mod_rewrite, see https://github.com/client9/libinjection/blob/master/src/fingerprints.txt#L4686). However I would expect things like. `count (9)` which is in the value reported to trigger alarms, as `COUNT()` can be an SQL construct.